# SharePoint online problem with HTML link in the column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, flow, json-formatting

I have nearly solved my problem how to open Attachment directly in web Browser from `SharePoint list` without downloading the file.

I have only problem with more then one Attachment.

**My Power automate flow**:

`1) When an item is created`

`2) Get attachments`

`3) Apply to each`

`3.1) Compose @items('Apply_to_each')?['AboluteUri']`

`4) Compose 2 @join(outputs('Compose'),' | ')`

`5) Update item @outputs('Compose_2')`

```
result:

https://sharepoint/pdf.1 | https://sharepoint/pdf.2
```

SharePoint list column is `Single line of text` with this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
 },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
 }
```

When I have only one attachment, works perfectly. Problem is if i have more then one. Two `https links` are merged to single one.

Do you have any idea how to separate those links as two or more single links? Maybe change something in the flow.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use **Multiple lines of text** (plain text) column for storing attachment file URLs instead of Single line of text column.

Then use below JSON formatting for your column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "padding": "11px 0",
    "min-height": "0"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "forEach": "item in split(@currentField,'|')",
      "attributes": {
        "href": "[$item]",
        "target": "_blank"
      },
      "txtContent": "[$item]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Before applying JSON**:

[image]

**After applying JSON**:

[image]

Comment: you are the best, works ! thank you

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: is there any option in JSON format to make link shorter ? for example pdf.1 and pdf.2 ?

Comment: Can you please [Ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with more details about your requirements? I will try to answer with explanation specific to your new question.