# SharePoint list - custom column with JSON format and Customize form

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, powerapp, powerapps-forms

In my last question [SharePoint online problem with HTML link in the column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305442/sharepoint-online-problem-with-html-link-in-the-column/305444?noredirect=1#comment322454_305444), [Ganesh Sanap](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69998/ganesh-sanap)
 figure out how put attachment to new column with `JSON` format to make them open without download needs.

My first question is, if is possible make that URL shorter in the `JSON` format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
  "display": "flex",
  "flex-direction": "column",
  "align-items": "flex-start",
  "padding": "11px 0",
  "min-height": "0"
  },
  "children": [
      {
      "elmType": "a",
      "forEach": "item in split(@currentField,'|')",
      "attributes": {
          "href": "[$item]",
          "target": "_blank"
       },
       "txtContent": "[$item]"
      }
    ]
  }
```

for example change `https://company.sharepoint.com/list/1.pdf` to `1.pdf` with working hyperlink.

second question is, how show this collumn in `Customize Form` in `PowerApp` to make it visible with hyperlink.

When i put in `Form` Source and Add `DataCard` I see the `links` but only as text. HyperLink not working.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON formatting like below to show only the file names instead of full URL:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "padding": "11px 0",
    "min-height": "0"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "forEach": "item in split(@currentField,'|')",
      "attributes": {
        "href": "[$item]",
        "target": "_blank"
      },
      "txtContent": "=substring([$item], lastIndexOf([$item], '/') + 1, indexOf([$item] + '^', '^'))"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

For showing the links on Power apps customized list form, you have to use the HTMLText control and apply similar logic as used in JSON formatting to split the URLs and then generate hyperlinks using `a` tags.